# How do I figure out the WSDL of a web service?

Tags: php, iis, wsdl

I feel like there must be something really simple that I'm not seeing here. I need a web page to talk with a web service, and for that I need the WDSL ... but I have no idea where I'm supposed to find it. I have full access to the web server, and all the code that underlies the web service. This is running on IIS, and I can see the folder that contains the web service. Basically, what I need to do turn this: "$client = new SoapClient('http://location');" into an actual location. The web service in question (along with most of what I'm working with) was created by someone else who is no longer available to answer questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that is written in C#, try with the following:

```
http://yourserver-virtualhost/webservicefolder/?wsdl
```

You should check IIS virtualhost mappings to see to which virtualhost is bound.

Try to find the source code, just in case you'll need changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 
`?WSDL` 
to web service location